# Why cmake file READ isn't finding /etc/os-release?

Tags: cmake, archlinux

---

The cmake code tries to read the content of /etc/os-release which in Arch Linux is a symlink to "../usr/lib/os-release" (relative path from /etc/ to the file /usr/lib/os-release). While `less /etc/os-release` works just fine, cmake fails complaining "no such file or directory".

Current cmake code:

```
file(READ "/etc/os-release" os_release)
```

Error I'm getting:

```
CMake Error at pkg/CMakeLists.txt:35 (file):
  file failed to open for reading (No such file or directory):

    /etc/os-release
```

I tried adding an IS_SYMLINK condition and getting the real path, but it doesn't even enter and go to the else statement:

```
if(IS_SYMLINK /etc/os-release)
    file(READ_SYMLINK "/etc/os-release" os_release)
    if(NOT IS_ABSOLUTE "${os_release}")
        get_filename_component(dir "/etc/os-release" DIRECTORY)
        set(os_release "${dir}/${os_release}")
    endif()
else()
    file(READ "/etc/os-release" os_release)
endif()
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Your first line of code works perfectly on my machine.

Comment: @Friedrich Thanks for your reply. Can you confirm your os-release is a sampling like mine?

Comment: What I did was to add a `message("${os_release}")` below and it shows the file's contents (`NAME` etc.) as if I had done `cat /etc/os-release`. The command `ls -la` prints `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Feb 28  2020 /etc/os-release -> ../usr/lib/os-release`.